# GCM (Google Cloud Messaging ) for Android, writing 3rd party server in .Net

Tags: android, .net, google-cloud-messaging

Need some help to implement 3rd party server for GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) for Android using .Net.

The official documentation gives guidelines for using it using servlet-api and gcm-server.jar ( java helper APIs for server side ).

Is there any equivalent for using it in .Net framework.
Any guideliness that would help to implement GCM using .Net?

Comment: it's 9 months later now.  Were you ever able to get this done?  I am looking to do exactly the same thing from my asp.net web api services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GCM documentation includes [the HTTP operations to be performed by the third-party server](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#server), including both the structure of requests and the structure of responses. You should be able to perform those HTTP operations from .NET.

Comment: How about Registering an Android device & it's app id using HTTP operations to retrieve it's reg_id?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by CommonsWare, you should write server-side code (web-services) to which allows to make `HTTP POST` to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` to send messages.

The Response & Request structures are mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#server) of GCM.